# Angularjs $resource, how do I know which obj is being passed to it? URL not receiving :id

Tags: angularjs, rest, mean-stack

I am using a MEAN stack and I am a little confused on how the $resource works. I understand that the $resource factory is a service that retrieves data for controllers. However, I have two model objects, Compositions and Critiques. What I am trying to do is get critiques based off the url, which looks something like this: /compositions/:compositionId/review.

For some reason whenever I call

```
Reviews.query(function(review) {
    console.log(review);
  $scope.reviews= review;

});
```

I get this error:

```
GET localhost:3000/compositions/review 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Here are my services:

```
angular.module('mean').factory('Reviews', ['$resource',

        function($resource) {
           return $resource('compositions/:docId/review', {
                docId: '@docId'
            },
            {
                update: {
                    method: 'PUT'
                }
            });
        }
    ]);

    angular.module('mean').factory('Compositions', ['$resource',
        function($resource) {
           return $resource('compositions/:compositionId', {
                compositionId: '@_id'
            },
            {
                update: {
                    method: 'PUT'
                }
            });
        }
    ]);
```

The second one works if I navigate to /compositions/:compId, but the first one does not. Instead I get the error above. Why isn't the docId being passed in? Any ideas? 
I want the compositionId, which is the docId in the 'critique' object models terms, but I want to get back critique objects. What am I doing wrong? Any  help or advice is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing callback to `query()` - that is wrong. You should pass there a params object with your docId. This is how you should do that (in Angular 1.2)

```
Reviews.query({docId: 5}).$promise.then(function(review) {
  console.log(review);
});
```